# How to create a sequence number in excel using based on two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a sequence number in excel based on two columns.

The input data I have looks like this

| acct id+product | tx_timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 10008 | 9/3/20 15:04 |
| 10008 | 9/9/20 22:42 |
| 10008 | 9/15/20 16:49 |
| 10008 | 9/18/20 2:43 |
| 10008 | 9/18/20 4:50 |
| 10008 | 9/30/20 4:10 |
| 10008 | 10/9/20 1:47 |
| 10008 | 10/9/20 1:56 |
| 1001 | 6/28/20 23:58 |
| 1001 | 6/29/20 3:56 |
| 10011 | 7/9/20 0:22 |
| 10011 | 7/9/20 0:40 |
| 10011 | 7/9/20 1:11 |
| 10011 | 7/9/20 1:32 |

The output I need is

| acct id+product | tx_timestamp | Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10008 | 9/3/20 15:04 | 1 |
| 10008 | 9/9/20 22:42 | 2 |
| 10008 | 9/15/20 16:49 | 3 |
| 10008 | 9/18/20 2:43 | 4 |
| 10008 | 9/18/20 4:50 | 5 |
| 10008 | 9/30/20 4:10 | 6 |
| 10008 | 10/9/20 1:47 | 7 |
| 10008 | 10/9/20 1:56 | 8 |
| 1001 | 6/28/20 23:58 | 1 |
| 1001 | 6/29/20 3:56 | 2 |
| 10011 | 7/9/20 0:22 | 1 |
| 10011 | 7/9/20 0:40 | 2 |
| 10011 | 7/9/20 1:11 | 3 |
| 10011 | 7/9/20 1:32 | 4 |

Where the sequence is incremented as long as `column 1` stays the same and then get reset .I have tried using fill and extending that doesn't seem to work , any help to point me to the right direction would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using this formula (in case you want this in "C" column):

```
=IF(A1=A2,C1+1,1)
```

As you can see, it increases the previous value but when the value in "A" column changes, you start back at 1.